# Проблема в Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ckeditor

Использую CKeditor.

На странице есть два textarea

```
<textarea name="discription"></textarea>
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
```

Прикручиваю ckEditor

```
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace('text', { width: '1000px' });
</script>

<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace('discription', { width: '1000px' });
</script>
```

Все работает нормально, но когда вбиваешь текст в один из textarea И там нажимаешь кнопку enter, он перекидывает скролл страницы на низ. Что за прикол не понятно. Что может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В каких-то версиях CkEditor был такой баг.
   Проявлялся, если добавить CkEditor к пустому элементу. Проявлялся не во всех браузерах, но как минимум в Firefox.
   Закостыливался добавлением скажем пробела к содержимому элемента.

   ```
    <textarea name="description">&nbsp;</textarea>  
    <textarea name="text">&nbsp;</textarea>
   ```
2. В последней версии CkEditor мне не удалось воспроизвести вашу проблему (смотрел в chrome/ff/ie11).
3. В английском нет слова "discription", зато есть слово "description"